# Apache POI doesn't quite give enough space when autosizing

Tags: java, linux, excel, fonts, apache-poi

I am building an Excel file with Apache POI.  After I add all of the content I autosize the columns using `sheet.autoSizeColumn(i)`.

Sometimes it doesn't quite give enough space.  I have tried `Verdana` and `Calibri-Regular` (had to switch to Calibri-Regular from Calibri because the autosize was going completely crazy all of a sudden on our Windows 7 boxes but worked fine on our Linux boxes, which is a mystery to me).  Is there something I can do to fix this?  Or is there a way to add a little padding after autosizing?

[image: sample Excel file that isn't quite spaced enough]

**Edit**:

On my Windows dev box I tried setting the font to Verdana with `font.setFontName("Verdana")`.  All of the content definitely changes to Verdana and the sizing on the columns is perfect.  On the Linux production box I used the bit of Java code that Gagravarr referenced in the below comments to print out a list of the fonts that Java sees.  I tried `Monospaced` but the spacing was identical to the above screenshot.  I then tried `Dingbats` and the content was still readable (which it shouldn't have been) while the spacing was really off (see screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Do you have all the required fonts installed on the machines *and* properly available to Java? POI uses the Java font metrics to work out how wide the columns will need to be, so it'll all go wrong if the fonts you use aren't available...

Comment: Use setColumnWidth(int columnIndex, int width).We can set column width as our wish.

Comment: @Gagravarr I checked the fonts installed on the Linux box with `fc-list` and was surprised to see that by default there are no fonts in common with Windows.  I guess I just never thought about it.  I tried creating a font with `workbook.createFont()` and not setting a name in hopes that it might just use a system default.  The Excel sheet still writes the content but with almost the exact same spacing as the picture above.

Comment: The system default on Linux may not be the same as on Windows! Can you try installing some fonts on linux + making sure Java can see them? That should hopefully fix it

Comment: @Gagravarr I sure will.  I guess I was thinking that if not setting a font name caused the system default to be used then regardless of which OS the autosize would work correctly because POI would be using a font that is installed.  What is the best way to check if Java can see a font?

Comment: With no font name set, POI will used a default font, but that may well not be the *right* font, so the sizing will be incorrect! See something like [this](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/swing-faq-list-fonts-current-platform) to list the fonts

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for the link!  I saw that `Monospaced` is one of the fonts listed on the Linux box so I changed the code, `normalFont.setFontName("Monospaced")`.  It still has the exact same spacing issue.

Comment: @Gagravarr On the Linux production box I tried setting the font to Dingbats, which is recognized by Java. The text is still readable (it shouldn't be) and the spacing is much more off than the picture above. Is `setFontName` not doing what I think it does?  If I use `setFontName("Verdana")` on my Windows dev side then the text definitely changes to Verdana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether this will resolve your problem or not, but if you have asked about "is there a way to add a little padding after autosizing?".... yes you can do it by following way.

```
testSheet.autoSizeColumn(ColIndex);
testSheet.setColumnWidth(ColIndex ,testSheet.getColumnWidth(ColIndex)+PaddingWidth);
```

Comment: That definitely worked for padding.  I really wish I could figure out why the autosize isn't working correctly since it feels a bit "hackish" fixing it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Also openjdk and Oracle JDK do not use the same font engine (SUN∕Oracle kept its  legacy engine for fear any change would break badly coded apps). It's quite possible openjdk will work better on linux for font stuff, since it reuses the same font libraries as the rest of the system, instead of reinventing a square wheel.

Fonts are a legal nightmare; Linux fonts licensing is usually liberal enough you can copy, modify and deploy them anywhere but the reverse is not true (Microsoft was very careful to create vendor lock-in for anyone foolish enough to build apps depending on Windows fonts)